# Why does Python ignore source files in favor of pyc files sometimes?

Tags: python, subprocess, filesystems

I've got a situation where I rapidly change Python source files on disk and, for each change, run them with Python in a subprocess (it's for a mutation testing tool). I have found that in some cases, the Python subprocess either doesn't see the change or ignores it in favor the contents of `__pycache__`. Here's an example:

```py
from pathlib import Path
import subprocess

workspace = Path('workspace')
workspace.mkdir(exist_ok=True)

for i in range(3):
    with open(workspace / 'code.py', mode='wt') as f:
        f.write(f"print({i})")
    proc = subprocess.run(
        'python -m code'.split(),
        stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        cwd='workspace')
    print(i, proc.stdout.decode('utf-8').strip())
```

I would expect this to print:

```
0 0
1 1
2 2
```

But generally it prints something like:

```
0 0 
1 0
2 0
```

or

```
0 0
1 1
2 1
```

That is, at some point the changes I'm writing to disk aren't seen by the Python subprocess.

I've tried all sorts of attempts to flush the changes to disk with `os.fsync`, `flush()` on the file handle, and so forth. The only thing that seems to make a difference is putting a substantial `time.sleep()` after the closing of the file handle.

I *could* tell Python to not use pycs by setting `PYTHONDONTWRITEBYTECODE`, but at this point I'd like to know what's going on.

So, am I right that this is just some failure to flush to disk? Or is there perhaps a bug/feature of Python that I'm fighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No special flushing is required, but aside from disabling or removing the `.pyc`, sleep is the only answer: the `.pyc` doesn’t appear **older** than the `.py` if the time elapsed between writing them is small enough. “Small enough” depends on the filesystem and OS, but it could easily be a whole second.

Comment: Ok, this makes perfect sense. I think I'll just disable pycs for now.